# Draw vector avatar using PHP or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, svg, vector

I'm working on a php project.

I'm provided with some data like race,height,weight,martial status,etc.
Based on these inputs, I want to draw a vector image, which can be a svg or any format.

Is it possible to do so? If it is possible, how can I do that?
I can't put some set of images and use them according to the data as, i have very huge data.

I want to draw a vector image dynamically based on the data.
Please help.

Comment: If you consider using php [GD and Image Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) is a starting point. Also you may use SVG or HTML5 canvas. Please decide for one of these, and provide more information about your project in order to get help.

Comment: I don't know whether i can use GD and Image functions. I will explore them and i will let you know.
However, without any base image, is it possible to draw a image with provided content on a empty canvas or in other way ? @enxaneta

Comment: What does [unity3d] have to do with this question?

Comment: I read some where that unity 3d uses javascript  and is used for gaming purpose drawing characters. i don't know whether it is correct or not ! so i just wanted to know. @Draco18s

Comment: Pencils can draw characters too, but unless that's the technology you're using, you shouldn't tag it. That's not what tags are for. Tags are for *future* askers to find questions *not* for you to ping technology experts.

Comment: Actually i'm trying on unity3d too. So that's why i tagged it. In the tags description of stackoverflow its mentioned that Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions. Not only for future askers. You can refer it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) . However i removed the tag now. @Draco18s

Comment: It does help experts find your question, too, yes. But experts in a technology who find your question (e.g. me) and don't see what your question has to do with that technology are going to question why the tag is there. *In theory* sure, Unity could do this too, but as "how do I do some vague task?" is not a good question for SO (hence the 3 "too broad" votes). Making that question also "in [language A, language B, language C, or language D]" makes that problem worse.

Comment: E.g. "I would like to do X task in Unity" is a better (although still broad) question than "I want to do this task, I don't care what platform, so I'm going to tag them all and hope one of them is right."